# write a function called steps() that builds a square staircase for any n

Tags: r

I am new to R and trying to figure out how to solve this problem.
write a function called steps() that builds a square staircase for any n.
[image]

this is what I have initially

```
steps<- function(n)

{
  mx <- matrix(,nrow=n,ncol = n)

  for( n in 1:n)
  {
    mx[n,n] = "#"


  }

  print(mx)
}
```

Comment: You can simply copy-paste the output  to your question instead of using images. Images tend to break screens and also(in my opinion) make the post sometimes crowded.

Comment: the image is what the code should ouput. My code does not output that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
steps <- function(n) {
  m <- matrix('', n, n)
  m[!upper.tri(m)[,n:1]] <- '#'
  m
}
steps(5)


#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,] ""   ""   ""   ""   "#" 
# [2,] ""   ""   ""   "#"  "#" 
# [3,] ""   ""   "#"  "#"  "#" 
# [4,] ""   "#"  "#"  "#"  "#" 
# [5,] "#"  "#"  "#"  "#"  "#"
```

If (like your image) you don't want to see the quotes, then

```
print(steps(5), quote = FALSE)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]                     #   
# [2,]                #    #   
# [3,]           #    #    #   
# [4,]      #    #    #    #   
# [5,] #    #    #    #    #
```